# compute current row col value based on values in current and previous row

Tags: netezza

Have table viz. `table1` which has `Time`, `Col1` and `Col2` fields. What I'm trying to do is to create a new table `table2` that includes the computed `Col3` values for each row based on `Col1` & `Col2` values of current and previous row in SQL of `table1`. The required format of `table2` is as below.

```
table2

   Time             Col1    Col2   Col3
   09:37.43.755       1      0      0.0    #=> col3 row1 start value = 0
   09:37.44.255       5      2      0.3333 #=> (row2.col2-row1.col2)/((row2.col2-row1.col2)+(row2.col1-row1.col1)) => (2-0)/((2-0) + (5-1)) => 2/6 = 0.3333
   09:37.44.755       10     2      0.0    #=> (row3.col2-row2.col2)/((row3.col2-row2.col2)+(row3.col1-row2.col1)) => (2-2)/((2-2) + (10-5)) => 0/5 = 0.0
   09:37.45.255       10     2      0.0    # similar to row2,3 but a div by 0 case => (2-2)/( (2-2) + (10-10)) = 0/0 => this should be mapped to 0 if the numerator is 0.
```

Comment: Are the id's always sequential?

Comment: I recommend you to do that on your application, sqlite does not have any function or support any analitical function which will turn the final query in a monster IF it is even possible.

Comment: Also, is the row 3 right? shouldn't it be `(row3.col2-row2.col2)...`?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, corrected. Need to do this in SQL only and more specifically Netezza.

Comment: @Sparky - I should remove the Id col, it is not present in the dataset. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool that will serve you the best here is probably the LAG windowed aggregate function. Still, there are probably a few different ways of doing this.  Here's one example, using LAG and a subquery.  The windowed aggregate functions are incredibly useful, so I'd say get to know them!

```
select * from table1 order by time, col1;

     TIME     | COL1 | COL2
--------------+------+------
 09:37:43.755 |    1 |    0
 09:37:44.255 |    5 |    2
 09:37:44.755 |   10 |    2
 09:37:45.255 |   10 |    2
(4 rows)


select time, col1, col2,
   coalesce ( case
      when (
            col2-lag_col2
         )
         + (col1-lag_col1) = 0 then 0
      else ((col2-lag_col2)*1.0/((col2-lag_col2)+(col1-lag_col1)))::NUMERIC(5,4)
   END , 0) col3
from (
      select time, col1, col2,
         lag(col1) over (order by time, col1) lag_col1,
         lag(col2) over (order by time, col1) lag_col2
      from table1
   )
   foo;

     TIME     | COL1 | COL2 |  COL3
--------------+------+------+--------
 09:37:43.755 |    1 |    0 | 0.0000
 09:37:44.255 |    5 |    2 | 0.3333
 09:37:44.755 |   10 |    2 | 0.0000
 09:37:45.255 |   10 |    2 | 0.0000
(4 rows)
```